# Missing printer filter epson 212-213

Tags: printing

I have looked in this forum and googled it, but cannot find a solution. My wireless printer used to work without any problems. Now, though, it says:

> ```
> File "/opt/epson-inkjet-printer-201302w/cups/lib/filter/epson_inkjet_printer_filter" not available: No such file or directory
> ```

I run Ubuntu 16.04

I did try to re-install the driver.

Comment: Did you try to install from the .deb file, or try to translate the .rpm file when you did the installation?

Comment: which printer do you have?

Comment: I used the .deb file, and as I said it has worked without problems for two years, then suddenly  missing some filter.

The only thing I have done in between would be a complete uninstall of Skype in order to re-install that. The uninstall required running sudo apt autoremove

Could that have done damage?

Comment: It is Epson XP 212

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.
I found the printer again and set it up. Then it worked fine, and I deleted the "old" printer from the printer overview and made the "new" one standard.